# Adding icon to project?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, deployment-project

i would like the installer to put an icon shortcut to my app created in vb.net. how do i do this?

i am using click once

edit:

i am using visual basic express 2008. perhaps it is not possible to add the icon to desktop using the built in installer?

Comment: Which installer do you use?
I'd suggest you to use InnoSetup

Comment: Do you mean put a shortcut on the Start menu and/or the quick launch bar?  Or do you mean you want the installer to use the same icon as your program?

Comment: using the same icon as project is fine

Comment: i am using the same installer as what comes with visual basic express, probably CLICKONCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean change the icon of the program so it is not a generic box thing? If that is the case, open your project, click the project menu, and select <project name> properties. Then, under the application tab, there is a place to browse for your icon:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope i want an icon added to the desktop after application is installed

Answer (score 2):

This is about embedded in VS Deployment Project

http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/1424/setupico.png [full size](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/1424/setupico.png)

So add an icon file to Application Folder, name it properly. After add a shortcut to Desktop (choose a project output as target) and setup icon (your ico file as target)

Comment: im sorry where do i find this screen? im using vb.net express 08

Comment: add new project to you solution: Add Project -> Other project types -> Setup and Deployment -> Setup Project

Comment: i dont have those options, i have add-->new project-> winform, class lib, wpf, console,

Comment: do you have a tree to the left of Add Project dialog with a list of project categories? http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/4222/addprojectsetup.png

Comment: Also I found this: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/437573-no-setup-project-2005-express-edition it seems that there is no Setup Projects in Express, only in Pro+ editions of VS, unfortunately.. but try Publish menu!

Comment: publish doesnt do it i just checked

Answer (score 0):

Every installer does that differently, depending on what you are using you should be able to find a feature to add the icon to the desktop.

What installer are you using? .Net Deployment wizard?